Remix hydration error when rendering current time
I was playing around with Remix when I ran into an unexpected error.
Basically, I'm trying to render a clock on my web page that prints the current time accurate to seconds. However, I've noticed the following errors when doing so.

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "9:21:48 AM" Client: "9:21:49 AM" Error Component Stack


Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.


An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.

I've noticed that the errors don't show up all the time, presumably because it only occurs when there's a mismatch between the time the page was rendered on the server and the time it reached the client. Moreover, this could an even bigger problem if the server and the client are in different time zones. I'm fairly certain that this is the problem, please correct me if I'm wrong.
I've tried to address this in several ways. Firstly, I tried using client only module in Remix using a .client folder and abstracting the part where it renders time into a separate component. However, this did not fix the problem as the client only modules are undefined on the server. The Remix documentation mentions this explicitly

Note that values exported from this module will all be undefined on the server, so the only places to use them are in useEffect and user events like click handlers.

So far the best solution I could find is something like this. I used useEffect to initialize the time state on initial render.
export default function Index() {
  const { visitCount } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const [time, setTime] = useState<Date>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date());
    }, 1000); // Update every second

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="center">
      <p>Current time: {time?.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
      <p>You have visited this site {visitCount} times.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

However, this introduces a substantial delay between the time the page is loaded and when the time appears on the page.
Is there a way I can specifically render some parts of my component exclusively on the client? I've seen some solutions but they're very old and the module required seem to no longer exist.
My folder structure is basically the latest remix template. I only made changes to _index.tsx file.
Edit: This does not appear to be a case of improper tag nesting unlike the problem mentioned here. I have a feeling this has got something to do with time mismatch on the server and the client as the error shows up only when the seconds counter is about to change.

Solution 1:
<p suppressHydrationWarning>Current time: {time?.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>

I followed this answer from this post.
Solution 2:
Return time from the loader function
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  // ...do whatever you need to do
  json({
    // other data,
    currentTime: new Date(),
  })
}

export default function Index() {
  const { currentTime } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const [time, setTime] = useState<Date>(new Date(currentTime));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <main className="center">
      <p suppressHydrationWarning>Current time: {time?.toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
    </main>
  );
}

This way the time from the server and client are the same at initial load time. The time loaded initially might be slightly off due to delays in transit. On subsequent seconds, the client side time will be loaded into the UI from within useEffect.
